# How can i copy elements in list to an array c/c++

Tags: c++, list

I have a list like:

```
list <char>mylist
```

I give it some elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    mylist.push_back(i);
}
```

My questtion is that if there is anyway to copy those elements from list to an array like

```
char A[10];
```

static array 
or

```
char *A= new char[10];
```

dynamic array

Comment: i <= 10 ==> invoked UB

Comment: The question is in **C++** programming language,so please do not write this **C/C++** or tag **both distinct programming languages at the same time**.

Comment: @rsp How did it invoke UB?

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal size of array is 10. So, you can access 0 to 9.

Comment: It hasn't invoked UB yet, but it will do if you try to copy all of the elements from your list into an array of size 10 (because there are 11 elements)

Comment: @rsp, but the array is still empty.

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal did some changes in question by OP.

Comment: It's funny, because the answer is "No, there is no way, to fit 11 elements from a list into a 10 element array."

Comment: @dinhvan2804 - You wanna know something funny? I was about to hit send on an answer right as your rude comment popped up. I'll leave the pleasure of dealing with you to someone else, if those are your sentiments.

Comment: @rsp The code was changed, to remove border case, but the point was, that even with it, there was no UB in presented code, because the loop just pushed values onto the list. There was no code reading or writing to the array, so there was no UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is that if there is anyway to copy those elements from list to an array

Yes, there is a way to copy objects from a container to another. You can use the following algorithm:

- get output iterator to the output container
- get input iterator to first element of the input container
- while input iterator does not point to the end

  - dereference the iterator to get a reference to the element
  - dereference the output iterator, and copy assign the element
  - increment both iterators

You don't need to write the loop yourself though because standard library already has done it for you: `std::copy`.